# How to fix capillary action on anti-condensation coating on box profile steel roofing sheets?

Tags: roofing, condensation

We have some carports here that were installed by a previous owner a few years ago.  They have side walls, but are open front and back, and have a steel box profile roof.  Big green sheets like this:

https://www.roofingsheetsbyrhino.com/box-profile-roofing-sheets/

The sheets have an anti-condensation coating on them, which probably does the job it's supposed to... but sadly wicks water from on top of the sheets all over the underside.  I initially naively thought it was coming up from the drip edge, so I scored the coating and tore a 4" strip of it off all along that edge.

That has helped, but I can see now that it's also problematic wherever the sheets overlap, especially on the end laps.  I think the coating should have been stripped off the sheets wherever there's an overlap, and some lapping tape put in there, but as far as I can tell they did neither thing.

I'm not sure how best to solve this.

1. take all the sheets off, trim the coating, add lapping tape, and re-fit...
2. seal the laps from above with some flashing tape or similar.  The roofs are very visible from further up the garden and the house, so I'd want some tape the same colour as the sheets which feels like a big ask!
3. other....?  Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a picture? Is this roof completely flat? Can you get your hands on a product like [Through the Roof!](https://www.sashco.com/products/through-the-roof/) and seal the overlaps?

Comment: Are you sure *wicking* is an action here?  Steel sheets are generally non-porous... more likely is condensation. There are no coatings which can stop that (outside of good insulation, but that is many inches thick OR needs climate control on the interior). Is the underside of the sheet humidity-controlled?   If you're seeing wicking on the end laps, what is the slope of the roof?

Comment: I have used the “through the roof’ on metal roofing, it is expensive and at a overlap a small bead could stop the capillary action squishing the bead flat and into the coating would seal it without having to remove and it is fairly clear but slightly yellows with time. I don’t think the slight discoloration will be noticeable (if you have the drip stop rib coating). That’s the only one I have worked with. Other than spray on closed cell both work well to stop drips.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus It's not flat, but it's pretty close - 1-3deg at a guess, certainly not as much as 5.  I'd be happy to lose 1ft of headroom at the low end if it was easy to do that... I have considered it!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Of course the steel is non-porous.  It's wicking between the steel sheets, in the overlap.  Not through the steel itself.

Comment: I should have specified that I'm in the UK - does anyone know if there's an equivalent product readily available here?  Through the Roof doesn't seem to come up on google shopping or amazon.

Comment: Codemonkey Although this gets into shopping , I looked and one of there listed vendors was Amazon. Through the roof MFG by sashco it may not be legal in your area I don’t know but there are 11 vendors on there map within 25 miles of me that carry it. The stuff even seals screw holes on my hay storage area.

Comment: Maybe, but you won't find it on amazon.co.uk (or I couldn't, anyway)

Answer (score 0):

> [PREPARATION & FITTING INSTRUCTIONS FOR ANTI-CONDENSATION ROOFING SHEETS](https://www.roofingsheetsbyrhino.com/anti-condensation-roofing-sheets/)
>
> INSTALLATION
>
> Note! This product is designed for use on roofs with a pitch of 10 degrees or greater.

And that's pretty typical of *all* steel roofs, and yours is the reason why.

The only way you can make a steel roof work on installations like this is if one piece of metal can span *the entire roof*.  Not half to a peak. (because you can't make the peak seam work either, same reason).  You can't have seams.

**The simple fact is, you have a flat roof.**  1-3 degrees is pretty much the minimum slope required to keep a flat roof from becoming a swimming pool, and is required by most roofing systems.  You need to use products appropriate to flat roofs, such as EPDM rubber.

Comment: To be clear, I didn't install the roof, it was here when we bought the place   I don't understand WHY they didn't put more of a pitch on it - there's easily enough space and height to...  I do understand that it's a problem, just trying to work out what the best thing I can do to fix it is.  Or if I should just live with a soggy underside and the treated lumber supports being wet for large portions of the year...

Comment: Need pics and it sounds thermal not a leak